# Theme isn't multilanguage ready. How can i still add a second language to the site?

Tags: multi-language, language, plugin-wpml

I have to add a second language to a site i maintain. The client purchased WPML for that purpose. But a lot of stuff is missing on the WPML translated version: The whole "portfolio section" for example. I contacted the theme author about the issue, and he told me that the theme isn't multilanguage ready.

Does someone have an alternative idea how i can still add the second language?

Answer (score 0):

You should edit the theme and add the use of translation API https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers at the appropriate places.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just stumbled upon the Plugin "qTranslate-X", which works like a charm. Not sure why WPML didn't...